# Alexander polynomial and surgery

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory

Some time ago I read that there is a relation between an evaluation of the multi-variable Alexander polynomial of a 2 component link, and the Alexander polynomial of the knot obtained by performing -1 surgery on one component. Does someone know where this result was first proved, or at least point to some paper that uses it? Thanks!